# How to get the indexed of a certain value from the pickerview?

Tags: json, swift, sorting

My app is trying to show the covid infection ranking (covid19api.com) of a country.
I have a pickerview to select the country and the basic covid info.
I sorted the data base on number of infection.
My question is how to get the indexed value　of the sorted array for the country base on the pickerview selection?

Tried using the "firstIndex" but is getting the following error :
Referencing operator function '==' on 'StringProtocol' requires that 'BasicCovidInfoParams' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Below is the code for the project:

```
struct BasicCovidInfo: Decodable {
    var Countries: [BasicCovidInfoParams]
}
struct BasicCovidInfoParams: Decodable {
    var Country: String?
    var NewConfirmed: Int?
    var TotalConfirmed: Int?
    var NewDeaths: Int?
    var TotalDeaths: Int?
    var NewRecovered: Int?
    var TotalRecovered: Int?
    var Date: String?
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
     
    //var basiccountrycovidinfo = BasicCovidInfoParams()
    var basiccountrycovidinfo = [BasicCovidInfoParams]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var rankFirstLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rankSecondLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rankThirdLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rankingLbl: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var covid19CountryPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalConfirmedLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalDeathsLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalRecoverdLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var toDateLbl: UILabel!
    
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        covid19CountryPicker.delegate = self
        covid19CountryPicker.dataSource = self
        
        getRemoteCovidJsonFile()
        
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return basiccountrycovidinfo.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
        totalConfirmedLbl.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: basiccountrycovidinfo[row].TotalConfirmed!))
        totalDeathsLbl.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: basiccountrycovidinfo[row].TotalDeaths!))
        totalRecoverdLbl.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: basiccountrycovidinfo[row].TotalRecovered!))
        
        
        let dataString = String(basiccountrycovidinfo[row].Date!)
        let from = dataString.index(dataString.startIndex, offsetBy:0)
        let to = dataString.index(dataString.startIndex, offsetBy:10)
        let newString = String(dataString[from..<to])
        //print(newString)
        toDateLbl.text = "Last Update : " + newString

        return basiccountrycovidinfo[row].Country
    }

    
    func getRemoteCovidJsonFile() {
        
        //Info source = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
        if let jsonUrlString = URL(string: "https://api.covid19api.com/summary") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonUrlString) { [self] (data, response, error) in
                
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        //decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                        let covidDataInfo = try decoder.decode(BasicCovidInfo.self, from: data)
                        //print(covidDataInfo.Countries[1].Country!)
                        self.basiccountrycovidinfo = covidDataInfo.Countries
                        
                        let array1 = covidDataInfo.Countries.sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
                            return a.TotalConfirmed! > b.TotalConfirmed!
                        }

                        let selectedText = pickerView(covid19CountryPicker, titleForRow: 0, forComponent: 0)
                        if let indexOfSelectedText = array1.firstIndex{$0 == selectedText!} {
                            print(array1[indexOfSelectedText])
                        }
               
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            rankFirstLbl.text = array1[0].Country
                            rankSecondLbl.text = array1[1].Country
                            rankThirdLbl.text = array1[2].Country
                    
                            covid19CountryPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        
                        }
                        
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                
            }.resume()
        }

    }
 
}
```

Comment: Your code appears ok witth loading your data and provides the !unsorted! version to the UIPicker for display. Then things go awry. Before providing the data to the UIPicker you seem to try to fetch some selected text which won't yield anything useful. Then you set some labels in a very uncoordinated way from your sorted array.

I _think_ you want to wait for the UIPickers action and set your labels witth the details of the selected country, but you do not understand the workings of UIPicker. Please read up on its documentation and provide it with the _sorted_ data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selectedRow` function of `UIPickerView` to get selected row. [Check documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow)

```
func selectedRow(inComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

Once you get the selected index value of picker, you can fetch the value from array using index property.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Your suggestion made me change the approach.
I have changed the approached by sorting it first before assigning it to the pickerview.